# php - parsing html doc but issue with comparing text content

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to retrieve a document and find some data within the HTML.

I've used Tidy clean and repair as the document contains lots of bad html.

Anyway,

In the html document there is a tag like:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Link 12345</a>
```

I want to get the value of the attribute (www.google.com) if the text content (Link 12345) matches a certain string.

```
$h2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

for ($i2; $i2 < $h2->length; $i2++) {
    $attr2 = $h2->item($i2)->getAttribute('href');



    if ($h2->item($i2)->textContent == "Link 12345")
        print "FOUND";
}
```

which doesn't seem to work. I know that the for loop returns 'Link 12345' at some point (when ->textContent is called). But the comparison always fails even though  Link 12345 appears if it is printed out. I suspect there is some issue with the encoding but I can't get it fixed.

Thanks.

Comment: Any specific reason you're not using PHP's [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php‎) loop?

Comment: Not really. I'm just using code I found online.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because "fix my found code" is not useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's **[DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)** to execute an XPath query against your DOM object.

I believe that for yours it'll be

```
//a[text()="Link 12345"]
```

Will return all the who's text is "Link 12345".

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. No results are found.

Comment: @user3083672: Then your text isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

A simple bug: you are testing "$h2->item($i2)->textContent" instead of "$h2->textContent"

Isn't it?